# Showing a function is a metric on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Question:
> For $x=\left ( x_{1},x_{2} \right ),y=\left ( y_{1},y_{2} \right ) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$
>
> Define $d\left ( x,y \right )=\max\left \{ \left | x_{1}-y_{1} \right |,\left | x_{2}-y_{2} \right | \right \}$.
>
> Show that $d$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

So, I've shown all the axioms except the triangle inequality which apparently is giving me a bit of problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|x_1 - y_1| \leq |x_1 - z_1| + |z_1 - y_1| \leq d(x,z) + d(z,y),$ and similarly for $|x_2 - y_2|$. Therefore

$d(x,y) = max\{|x_1 - y_1|,|x_2 - y_2|  \} \leq d(x,z) + d(y,z)$

Comment: Why is the second inequality less than or equal to? isn't the absolute value of x-z +z-y =d(x,z)+d(z,y)?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want to show that $d(x,y) \leq d(x,z) + d(z,y)$. The second inequality follows directly from the definition of $d$.

Comment: The definition says:
$d\left ( x,y \right )=\max\left \{ \left | x_{1}-y_{1} \right |,\left | x_{2}-y_{2} \right | \right \}$.
How is $\left | x_{1}-z_{1} \right |+\left | z_{1}-y_{1} \right |\leq d\left ( x,y \right )+d\left ( z,y \right )$?

Comment: Don't you mean $d(x,z) + d(z,y)$? $|x_1 - z_1| \leq max\{|x_1 - z_1|, |x_2 - z_2|\}$ and $|z_1 - y_1| \leq max\{|y_1 - z_1|, |y_2 - z_2|\}$

Comment: and if $a \leq b$ and $c \leq d$, then $a + c \leq b + d$. This is a property of real numbers.

Comment: I notice. There's definitely a lot of algebraic manipulation going on.
I cannot seem to understand the reason for the first inequality though.

Comment: No there is no algebraic manipulation happening. It is just using the definition of $max$, along with triangle inequality of absolute value, and basic order properties of real numbers.

Comment: Thanks. Might be worth a visit back to basic properties of reals. Been dabbling in Abstract Algebra for way too long.

Answer (score 0):

We want to show $d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$ for all $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Put $x=(x_{1},x_{2}),y=(y_{1},y_{2}),z=(z_{1},z_{2}).$ Without loss of generality, suppose $|x_{1}-y_{1}|\leq|x_{2}-y_{2}|$. So $$d(x,y)=|x_{2}-y_{2}|\leq|x_{2}-z_{2}|+|z_{2}-y_{2}|\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y).$$